# Mongoose Date.now() + 1 year

Tags: date, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```
const equipSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

dateConducted: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
calibrateDue: {
    type: Date,
    default: () => Date.now() + 365 days || 1 year  // add 1 year from now 
}
});

module.exports = restful.model('Equipment', equipSchema);
```

How to add on the line for the ***calibrateDue*** field the default date should set to +1 year.

Answer (score 1):

Alter the following statement and try

Instead of

```
Date.now() + 365 days || 1 year
```

Use

```
Date.now() + 365*24*60*60000
```

In the above statement `365*24*60*60000` means

```
365 days = 365*24*60*60000 = 365 x 24 hours x 60 minutes x 60 seconds x 1000 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function like this:

```
    var oneYear = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    var myOneYearLater = function() { return new Date(Date.now() + oneYear);};
```

And in your schema, give `calibrateDue` as:

```
    calibrateDue: {type: Date,
                   default: myOneYearLater}
```